# PHP get user id in url

Tags: php, string, session

Im very new to PHP, so I have a bit of a challenge here.
Right now, im trying to get the specific user id in the url, so its possible for me to change content according to what user that is logged in.
(Showing different profile texts, names, ages and such)

I have tried this: header("Location: profile.php?id=$id"); but it dosent seem to work.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])!="") {
    header("Location: index.php");
}

include_once 'dbconnect.php';

//check if form is submitted
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '" .     $email. "' and password = '" . md5($password) . "'");

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $_SESSION['usr_id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['usr_name'] = $row['name'];
        header("Location: profile.php?id=$id");
    } else {
        $errormsg = "Incorrect Email or Password!!!";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: don't escape passwords. Ones such as `123'\abc` are perfectly valid and you are probably limiting passwords. You should use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` instead.

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])!="")` that is a false positive btw; you need to break that up into two separate conditions.

Answer (score 0):

change your code from

`header("Location: profile.php?id=$id");`

to

`header("Location: profile.php?id=" . $row['id']);`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `$id` defined anywhere. Use
`header("Location: profile.php?id={$row['id']}");`

Also mind, that you should check on profile.php if it is logged user - unless you want to lookup diffrent user data by just swaping id around. Best if you use your `$_SESSION` variable on profile.php - just access it there, it is global.

Also, don't use md5 for password hashing - right now it is not very secure (use [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)), same as concatenating your sql query. Use [binding params](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Answer (score 0):

You already have the ID available in the [session](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php). Use `$_SESSION['usr_id']` to access it from `profile.php`.

Do not pass the user id in the URL, as this can be easily faked. Never trust user input.

Answer (score 0):

$id = $row['id'];

header("Location: profile.php?id=$id");